# CSS shadows and rounded corners in bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Are there any css hacks to make come up with this image below with bootstrap nav-tab markup? Having the rounded corners with shadows in it?

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">ABOUT OUR SEASONINGS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">GET RECIPE IDEAS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#yellow" data-toggle="tab">INGREDIENTS & NUTRITION INFO</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="red">
    <h1>Red</h1>
    <p>red red red red red red</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="orange">
    <h1>Orange</h1>
    <p>orange orange orange orange orange</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="yellow">
    <h1>Yellow</h1>
    <p>yellow yellow yellow yellow yellow</p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

I'm thinking of making it

Comment: There are no 'hacks', you just have to restyle default bootstrap nav tabs. Particularly look at the `border-bottom` on the `nav-tabs` class. Give it some shadow. Restyle `nav-tabs>li>a`, give it a background color, some shadows, etc.

Comment: If you can show us what attempts you have made to add the shadows we might be able to help further. I'm not sure "hacks" are really what you are after....just proper CSS.

Comment: @nationalholiday Thank you for the comment, but I already anticipated that and think many times of it, what should I do to make that type of layout in pure CSS, but if you look closely to the image, the shadows and tab slants are quite complicated to be implemented using css

Answer (score 2):

Here I provide the complete example to create bootstrap tab panel with a rounded border.

```js
 $(function(){
    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).tab('show');
    })
  });
```

```css
html{
  margin: 20px 10px auto;
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
} 
.nav:after,
.nav:before {
  content:"";
  display: table;
} 
.nav:after {
  clear:both;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.nav {
  zoom: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.nav li {
  list-style: none outside none;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.nav .active {
  z-index: 3;
}
.nav li:before,
.nav li:after,
.nav  a:before,
.nav  a:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;

}

.nav a {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgb(97, 142, 70);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(30) rotateX(10deg);
}
.nav .active a {
  background: #F66599;
  color:#BE3569;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(30) rotateX(10deg);
}



.nav  a:before {
  left:-20px; 
}
.nav  a:after {
  right: -20px;
}

.nav .active:before,
.nav .active:after {
  z-index: 1;
  background: #F66599;
}

.nav li:first-child a:before,
.nav li:last-child a:after {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.tab-content {
  background: rgba(60, 118, 61, 0.17);;
  color:#444444;
  padding: 20px;
}
.tab-pane {
  display: none;
}
.tab-pane.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
 
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home page</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="portfolio">Portfolio page</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Messages page</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Setting page</div>
</div>
```

To Add CSS shadows use following css

```
.tab-content {    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -5px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -5px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); box-shadow: 0px -5px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); }
```

jsfiddle : [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/W3CodeSchool/jp8ajj6k/)

Ref: [w3codeschool.com](http://www.w3codeschool.com/question/bootstrap-tabs-with-round-out-borders-and-display-like-chrome-browser/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

CSS:

```
.nav-tabs{
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #777;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus{
      -webkit-transform: perspective(30) rotateX(10deg);
}
```